# NumericUpDown error message

Tags: vba, numericupdown

I am a newbie to Visual Basic and I have a question that hopefully has a simple answer.
I have two `NumericUpDown` buttons and I need to show an error message if the second one is bigger than the first one. (I.E. "the value for the second NumericUpDown must be equal to or higher than the value of the first NumericUpDown").

I know the second part will be

```
MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
```

How do I tell Visual basic to only show this error message when the circumstances above happen?

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the two values, and show your message if the second is less than the first.

```
If numericUpDown2.Value < numericUpDown1.Value Then
  MessageBox.Show("The value for the second number " & _
                  "must be equal to or higher than the value " & _
                  "of the first number", "Error", _
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Comment: I presume that this code needs to go into the Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged (...) and Sub NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged(...)

Comment: If you pop up the error every time the value is changed, you're going to tick off some users. I'd check it just before you use it for something (save it, do a calculation, etc.) instead, but that's your choice. You didn't ask where you should put the code, though; you just asked how you would "tell Visual basic to only show...when".